# Resize listview according to edittext no of lines

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, chat

I am stuck in one issue. I took edit text below list view just like chat application. Whenever i press enter key for new line list view does not change its position. I want listview should always display above edittext. Currently edittext displays behind the listview. When i scroll the listview then it displayed above edittext. Please help.

-->

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
    <EditText 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/chat_msg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/type_message"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:layout_width="0dip">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/send_chat_icon"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/send_msg"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/sub_fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/signuphome_headingbg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/follower"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/friends"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_whisper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="+" />
    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/follower_list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selected_contacts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/follower_listView"
       android:layout_below="@+id/heading_layout"
       android:layout_above="@+id/selected_contacts"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
       android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/selected_contacts"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Done"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your source. please. there're no fortune tellers here

Comment: can You post Your xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

here's a pseudo-XML that works for what you want. pretty basic stuff.

```
<RelativeLayout

  <CommentArea align_BottomParent = true;/>
  <ListView align_TopParent = true;
            align_Above="commentArea"/>
/>
```

Comment: I have updated question with layout.xml i have used. Can you help me?